# How do I call or find a way to get bottom nav bar to work with stateless widgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  static List<Widget> _pages = <Widget>[
    inputPage(),
    leaderboardsPage(),
    userInfo(),
  ];
```

I have the above widget list and the one of the stateless widget class is initialised as follows:

```
class userInfo extends StatelessWidget {
```

and they are called in a bottom nav bar as follows

```
child: _pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
```

However, I need to change userInfo to

```
class userInfo extends State<ProfilePage> {
```

because I need to use setState() and I cannot use setState if userInfo() is a Stateless Widget.

Any workaround that you can think of. I am fairly new to Flutter and Dart so I don't know all about Widgets and States. Here's the needed code:

```
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;

  ProfilePage({required this.user});

  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
  static List<Widget> _pages = <Widget>[
    inputPage(),
    leaderboardsPage(),
    userInfo(),
  ];
```

```
class userInfo extends State<ProfilePage> {
  userInfo();

  bool _isSendingVerification = false;
  bool _isSigningOut = false;

  late User _currentUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _currentUser = widget.user;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sakirt Meter'),
    ),
    body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
                child: Image.asset('assets/icon.png', fit: BoxFit.contain, height: 100),
                //child: Text('Login', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,),
              ),
              Text(
                'NAME: ${_currentUser.displayName}',
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what you are doing but I will let you know you should absolutely not declare your own `State` class for another stateful widget, you should make a new stateful widget:

```
class UserInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  _UserInfoState createState() => _UserInfoState();
}

class _UserInfoState extends State<UserInfo> {
  ...
}
```

If you need to access `ProfilePage`'s values from `UserInfo`, you should do by passing said values as arguments:

```
class UserInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserInfo({required this.user});

  final User user;

  @override
  _UserInfoState createState() => _UserInfoState();
}

class _UserInfoState extends State<UserInfo> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _currentUser = widget.user;
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

then on `ProfilePage`, you need to make some changes aswell:

```
List<Widget> get _pages => <Widget>[
    inputPage(),
    leaderboardsPage(),
    userInfo(user: widget.user),
  ];
```

`_pages` can't be static because it uses `user`, which is not static, I also made it into a getter so it works properly even if `user` changes.

If what you want is to rebuild or call setstate on `ProfilePage` from `UserInfo`, you can use a callback.

Let's say I want `ProfilePage` to rebuild on the press of a button on `UserInfo`:

```
lass UserInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserInfo({required this.user, required this.onChanged});

  final User user;
  final VoidCallback? onChanged

  @override
  _UserInfoState createState() => _UserInfoState();
}

class _UserInfoState extends State<UserInfo> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _currentUser = widget.user;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: Text('press me!'),
      onPressed: widget.onChanged,
    );
  }
}
```

Then on the pages getter:

```
  List<Widget> get _pages = <Widget>[
    inputPage(),
    leaderboardsPage(),
    userInfo(
      user: widget.user, 
      onPressed: () => setState(() {
        // some code or something :)
      }),
    ),
  ];
```

Comment: This has helped greatly man, I managed to solve my issue. Thanks a lot  :)

Comment: You are welcome! Happy you solved the issue!